# on your macbook, show your IDEA scala plugin version which can working?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

my idea conf:
macbook 10.7
idea:11.1.2  build #IU 117.418
scala plugin version: 0.5.907

the result is: scala cannot pass compiling.

show your can working conf, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2 Build #IC 117.418 with Scala Plugin version 0.5.913.

I had issue getting the plugin to recognize *.scala file. The forum told me to check the File Types setting, and I had to manually add *.scala to Scala files.

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Download [scala-2.9.2.tgz](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.9.2.tgz) and expand it as `~/Applications/scala-2.9.2/`.
2. Download [scala-docs-2.9.2.txz](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-docs-2.9.2.txz) and expand it as `~/Applications/scala-2.9.2/scala-devel-docs/api/`.
3. From IntelliJ, File > New Project...

   - Select *Create project from Scratch*.
   - Type in project name.
   - Keep the *Create module* as is. *Java Module* is fine.
   - Hit *Next*.
4. Keep *Create source directory* checked.

   - Hit *Next*.
5. Check *Scala*:

   - Keep *Use Scala distribution* checked.
   - Browse to `~/Applications/scala-2.9.2/` that you created above.
   - Rename *Create compiler library* to `scala-compiler-2.9.2`.
   - Rename *Create standard library* to `scala-library-2.9.2`.
   - Keep them both *project-level*.
   - Hit finish.
6. Right click `src`, and select New... > Scala Class.

   - Type `Hello` for Name.
   - Select *Object* for Kind.
   - Hit *OK*.
7. This should create `object Hello`.
8. Type this in:

   ```
   object Hello extends App {
     println("Hello, world!")
   }
   ```
9. Right-click on *Hello* icon from the Project tree and select *Run 'Hello.main()'*.
   This should print out the following:

   ```
   /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Didea.launcher.port=7532 ....
   Hello, world!

   Process finished with exit code 0
   ```

Comment: i follow your step, still compile err. here is screenshot: http://www.pusuo.net/tmp/Snip20120716_2.png   thanks

Comment: are you on mackbook? it's different from macpro

Comment: Your "j" icon indicates that the file is not being treated as a Scala object. It should have "O" icon. Did you check the File Types setting?

Comment: yes, have setted the scala file type *.scala.  thank a lot :)